# Indentation errors with code block?

Tags: python, if-statement, calculator, arcgis, arcmap

I tried to define the following functions, but I keep getting:
`error 000989 : Python syntax error: <value>`.

So apparently my code has improper syntax. I've tried the following:

```
def yieldCalc(value):
 if (value=1):
     return 6.2
  elif (value=2):
     return 7.9
  else:
     return 8.21
```

Also

```
def yieldCalc(value):
 if (value=1):
     return 6.2
  elif (value=2):
     return 7.9
 else:
     return 8.21
```

And

```
def yieldCalc(value):
 if (value=1):
     return 6.2
 elif (value=2):
     return 7.9
 else:
     return 8.21
```

What is the proper way to indent the python code block?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in python you should use double equal signs `==` to compare two values:

```
def yieldCalc(value):
    if value == 1:
        return 6.2
    elif value == 2:
        return 7.9
    else:
        return 8.21
```

Please see the following links from python's documentation for more information on indentation and comparisons:

[Style Guide - Indentation](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#indentation)

[Built-in types - Comparison](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#comparisons)

Comment: you should add a comment about proper indenting to this answer

Comment: thanks, I added links to the official documentation.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple fundamental problems with your code. If you have pasted your code that you are using above, then you are not following the [PEP-8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) standard.

1. [Use 4 spaces per indentation level](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#indentation). In your first indentation you are using a single space.
2. If you are testing that the value of variable `value` is 1, then you should be using `==` - a single `=` is an [assignment statement](http://anh.cs.luc.edu/python/hands-on/3.1/handsonHtml/variables.html).

```python
def yieldCalc(value):
    if value == 1:
        return 6.2
    elif value == 2:
        return 7.9
    else:
        return 8.21
```

Comment: not followinh pep8 isn't really a problem that leads to errors. inconsistent indentation, however, does lead to errors.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everyone who responded, as it turns out what I had wrong was - as all of you pointed out - the syntax used for declaring the logical test in my if.

I used == instead of = and kept the indentation as suggested by Larry.

It works and I saved a lot of time.